# Coldfusion ORM CFC Mapping

Tags: orm, coldfusion, relationship, cfc

I use a dotted notation for my CFC relationship mappings but I have noticed that they sporadically don't work.

I tried setting a mapping up for my site root in coldfusion administrator and using that to point towards the relational mappings but unfortunately that doesn't always work.

It works on my development server but not on the two different live servers I have tested.

I considered taking the dotted notation mapping out and using the cfc name instead but that doesn't work sometimes too.

We also have another mapping that works for all our siteroots, this one is set programatically and works most the time for mappings as well.

I am wondering how CF reads and interprets the mappings. why would it ignore a mapping set in cfadmin? why would it randomly not be able to find relationships?

> Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface
>
> path.to.cfc.from.siteroot
>
> Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface
>   exists.

Comment: What kind of error messages do you get? What version of CF are you on?

Comment: added error message. its just the default 'can't find' message.